# Adding prefix to Nextjs dynamic route

Tags: next.js

I have quite a lot of routes defined and one of the routes is dedicated to user profiles.

Each user has a public profile accessible from HTTP://example.com/@username.

I have tried creating file `pages/@[username].js` but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to have this behavior without passing @ sign with the username because this would greatly complicate index.js handling homepage and I would like to have that code separated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Next.js does not support this yet.

You should watch this [issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9081).

Comment: It does support it now, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929729/7869175

Answer (score 11):

You can now do this like so in `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/@:username',
        destination: '/users/:username'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will make any link to `/@username` go to the `/users/[username]` file, even though the address bar will show `/@username`.

Then, in your `/pages/[username].tsx` file:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function UserPage() {
  const { query = {} } = useRouter()

  return <div>User name is {query.username || 'missing'}</div>
}
```

Comment: okay tested working. ```const router = useRouter();
  const { username } = router.query;````

Comment: I added an example with `useRouter` to my answer.

Comment: Btw the slug is passed a props automatically no need to call `userRouter`

export default function Page({ params }) { console.log (params.username) }

Comment: You aren't always accessing params from the root page though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Next.js 14 with App Router. This works both for `/@username` and nested paths like `/@username/about`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/@:username/:path*',
        destination: '/users/:username/:path*',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```