# How to use the same slug for different routes in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

Title may be kinda confusing - I just want to have routes like `/<slug>` and `/@<username>` while the first one uses a different page than the second. How to achieve that in Next.js?

Comment: have you tried ``index.js`` for ``/<slug>`` and ``@[username].js`` file for ``/@<username>`` ??

Comment: Yep, unfortunately, didn't work.

Comment: Checkout this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929729/5882307